# Calculate the value of  from the infinite series in c

Tags: c

I am trying to make a C program that calculates the value of `Pi` from the infinite series, aka Leibniz series, and display it to the user. My problem is that I need to display a special message that appears when the program hits the first `3.14`, and the first `3.141`. That special message should include in which iteration of the loop did the the number become `3.14` and `3.141`. I am not lazy so a found a way to make the infinite series but the second part I couldn't figure out, so what should I add to my code to make it display the special message?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, den; // denominator and counter
    double pi = 4;

    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        den = i * 2 + 3;
        // (4 - 4/3 + 4/5 -4/7 + 4/9 -......)
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            pi = pi - (4.0 / den);
        }
        else {
            pi = pi + (4.0 / den);
        }

        printf("pi = %lf\n", pi);
    }
}
```

Comment: "irritation" is an interesting typo!  "Iteration can be irritating" sounds like it might be a song.

Comment: Please format your code consistently.  I am not clear what the condition is for triggering the message.  I.e. do you want to compare the value of pi from last iteration with this iteration?  How do you know if a given digit has converged?

Comment: It's not super elegant, but just use a flag to record if you already printed a value and do a range check.  eg `if( !flags[0] && pi >= 3.135 && pi < 3.145 ){  printf("%d: pi = %.2lf\n", i, pi); flags[0] = 1; }`

Comment: If I understand the question, I would use `snprintf(buf,sizeof buf,"%.50lf",pi)` to convert the value of `pi` to a string, and then use `strncmp` to check how many digits of the string match the true value of PI.

Comment: Brute-forcing a non-linear comparison gets very hard to get right, transforming into a string is fairly easy. As long as your programme has a limit on the precision that is less than the precision of `M_PI`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int
main (void)
{
  int i, den;                   //denominator and counter
  int prec = 0;
  double pi = 4;

  for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
      den = i * 2 + 3;
      //(4 - 4/3 + 4/5 -4/7 + 4/9 -......)
      if (i % 2 == 0)
        pi -= 4.0 / den;
      else
        pi += 4.0 / den;

      //printf ("pi = %lf\n", pi);

      if (prec < 1 && trunc (100 * pi) == 314)
        {
          printf ("Found 3.14 at iteration %d\n", i);
          prec++;
        }
      if (prec < 2 && (int)trunc (1000 * pi) == 3141)
        {
          printf ("Found 3.141 at iteration %d\n", i);
          prec++;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
pi = 2.666667
pi = 3.466667
pi = 2.895238
...
pi = 3.150140
pi = 3.133118
pi = 3.149996
Found 3.14 at iteration 117
...
pi = 3.141000
pi = 3.142185
pi = 3.141000
Found 3.141 at iteration 1686
...
```

Comment: You need to tweak the precision on the format string.  Otherwise, it looks like a defect, when you don't trigger the special message when "pi = 3.141000" is printed the first time in your output.  It took me a while to figure out.  Heh.

Comment: I would like to thank you Davide because your answer is the most appropriate for my current level in programming . And also I would like to thank everyone than took the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that compares the first n digits of a double `cmp_n()`.  Variables use minimal scope.  The variable `oracle` holds the truncated `pi` to `n` decimals.  The values of `oracle` must be stored in ascending order.  I tweaked the pi formula to be a bit more compact format.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int cmp_n(double d1, double d2, size_t n) {
    return fabs(trunc(pow(10, n) * d1) - trunc(pow(10, n) * d2)) < 1.0;
}

int main() {
    double pi = 4;
    size_t o = 0;
    struct {
      double pi[;
      size_t n;
    } oracle[] = {
       { 3.14, 2 },
       { 3.141, 3 }
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        int den = i * 2 + 3;
        //(4 - 4/3 + 4/5 -4/7 + 4/9 -......)
        pi += ((i % 2) ? 4.0 : -4.0) / den;
        int special = 0;
        if(
            o < sizeof(oracle) / sizeof(*oracle) &&
            cmp_n(pi, oracle[o].pi, oracle[o].n)
        ) {
            special = 1;
            o++;
        }
        printf("pi = %.15f%2s\n", pi, special ? "*" : "");
    }
}
```

and the relevant data (with line numbers);

```
$ ./a.out | nl -v0 | grep '*'
   117  pi = 3.149995866593470 *
  1686  pi = 3.141000236580159 *
```

Note: you need to add the "%.15lf" format string other the pi output is rounded.  `double` only gives you about 15 digits, and the `cmp_n()` scales the number and this may not work as expected as you get close to the precision supported by `double`.

Comment: `fabs` might compare very small, but not the place value. _Eg_, 1.000 and 0.999 matched no decimal places. Is your code aware of that?

Comment: fabs() is only used to convert a signed difference to a unsigned value to make the < 1.0 work.  Otherwise I need to checked that the signed value is between -1.0 and 1.0.  trunc(pow(10, n) * ...) takes care of the only looking at n digits.  This will break horrible just like the pi calculations if you want more decimal digits than double offers.